# Performance issue with UIVisualEffectView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uivisualeffectview

I have UITableView with 10 big images like Instagram and i have some blurview on that images. I add my visualeffects UITableViewCell like that;

```
_blurButtonEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

_visualButtonEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:_blurButtonEffect];
_visualButtonEffectView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;

_visualEmojiEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:_blurButtonEffect];
_visualEmojiEffectView.layer.cornerRadius = 24.0f;

_visualButtonEffectView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_visualEmojiEffectView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

_visualButtonEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(20.0f, _button.frame.origin.y + 7.0f, 48.0f, 48.0f);
_visualEmojiEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(_emoji.frame.origin.x - 4.0f, _button.frame.origin.y + 22.0f, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2) - 25.0f, 30.0f);
```

If button title is null, i show _visualEmojiEffectView and hide _visualButtonEffectView. Otherwise _visualButtonEffectView is always shown. While i'm scrolling my UITableView, performance is perfect but this blur effects shown so annoying, they seems like flashing with every scroll movement and touches. I can block this with this in cell;

```
self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
self.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

If i'm rasterize my cell like that, blur effect works perfect but scrolling performance is awful even on iPhone 6. What is the correct way to configure UIBlurEffectView with UITableViewCell?

Comment: `self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;`
`self.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;` Helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is too late to reply but still i hope this helps someone.  You can give a white background colour to the visual effect view with a very low alpha. Something like this:

```
[_visualButtonEffectView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.2]];
```

You may also try using UIToolbar instead of a visual effect view. It does not give exactly the same effect but will still be good enough.

Comment: This sort of helped me, this improves the problem, there is far less flickering with this. But its not gone completely :(